# How is a request to SQL made in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, t-sql

I actually have a Backend high complexity, high volume TSQL-Database at the moment with Frontend from VBA (Access) and planned to add (or later replace the Access) with a JavaScript Frontend.

Now it seems to me, it could be much better to directly make this in Dart/Flutter to be able to at least set up a Basis for all platforms (MacOS, IOS, Android, Windows). However I was not able to find a single example to connect a Dart Frontend with a TSQL Database.

Can someone send or link an example of how code could look like when sending and receiving/using e. g. a SELECT to the IP of a SQL database?

Thanks in advance!

I already searched for Dart/flutter in combination with SQL/TSQL on YT, Google and stackoverflow and some similar forums.

All I found seemed more related to other ways on the one or the other side like Lazarus or MySQL

My best hit was database_sql 0.0.2-package but without documentation, dart conventions not fulfilled and with only few reference I am not sure if this is the way to go.

Best Christian

Edit:
Ich habe mir nun folgenden Code erarbeitet. Wenn jemandem was besseres einfällt gern her damit! :-):

```
    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> selectFieldFromTable(String field, String table) async {
  final Database db = await openDatabase('my_db.db');
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT $field FROM $table');
  return result;
}
```

Edit2:
First of all, I'm experimenting. As I am not convinced if this project is suitable for flutter/dart... but I think Dart/Flutter is a great tool with future and I want to reach out how far I can go with it. Especially on security aspects which is crucial if you directly connect from the Flutter app to the database (I would never include crucial data in such a directly connected database of course, just convenience data).

What I want to do is to have clientside information stored in such a directly connected database such as clientside settings, Language (for the User-Interaction before Backend connection). This is applicable only for info that should also be available when the webserver/backend is not available. In other projects I used several databases including small local databases running on the same device in order to much more separate information so that e. g. really sensitive information is only available when directly connected to the hardware so that even when you are in the local network you have no connection to it. See below model for (hopefully) more clarity - it is still just an excerpt of the actual system:

Main Server (no connection to any network)

^

|

Administratorgateway (while hardwareconnected - connection to the Server-Database - possibility to switch on / off connection to local network to upload data to local server) - there are several personal gateways (data protection, human ressources, financials) to single entry points and without automated connection.

|

v

Local Server (connection to Local network, no connection to Main Database, KI- and Request-triggered catch and drop of data)

| ^

v |(requests)

webadmin machine (connection to local network, switch on/off for Webserver)

|

v

Webserver (databse only contains requested data from conformed requests, no full database)

| ^

v |

Backend (automatically controls requests to the database)

^ |

| v

Client-Database (no sensitive data - function - language - environment - local service)

| ^

v |

Client-Side-(Back-)Middleend

| ^ |

| | v

| | Flutter-side-Database

| | ^

| | |

Client (has connection to Backend and to the Client-Database (fast data))

My idea for the Dart/Flutter App is to switch from webservice (when mobile) to local mode(e.g. in the office - still clientside but with clientside (back-)Middleend) where a mobile device may directly connect to a local network where the database runs.

I don't know exactly if I want to set up a database on a mobile device - SQLite or so - as I guess this is not the conception but it could eventually be used to preload excerpt data from the database to work with it (e.g. during flightmode).

Comment: Dart/Flutter is a language normally used for developing web and mobile apps. You can also build server apps, targeting a specific platform, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_(programming_language)#Deploying_apps. It's not clear to me where do you want to host this app.

Comment: Usually, a front-end does not connect directly to the database. It connects to a backend (using HTTP calls) and the backend connects to the database. Do you want to build the backend in Dart/Flutter or the frontend?

Comment: Anyway, on https://pub.dev/packages?q=sql+server we can find a few libraries that can connect to SQL, including https://pub.dev/packages/connect_to_sql_server_directly. I have not used any of them, because I have zero experience in Dart/Flutter.